# Assign numpy ndarray to list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

Can someone help me with my question. I have created a loop which in every execution produce a numpy.ndarray of size (5,) but when the loop terminates and I want to print the results of my code it  only print the last ndarry of size 5, I tried to assigned the results in a list but I get "too many indices for array"

```
k=0;
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if table[i, j] != 0:
            k=k+1;
            inv=np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.T,X));
            theta[k,:] = np.dot(inv,X.T).dot(HSI[i,j,:])
```

I want to assign the results on theta[] so if I want to print the result from the second execution I will write theta[1] and so on.

Most likely my false is on the last line

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You can create an empty list `l = []` and `l.append(result)` to the list. In your code, what are `M`, `N`, `table`, `X`, `theta`, and `HSI`?  It is easier for us to help you if you provide runnable code. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question is hard for me to understand.  Can you post an example that I could run locally, where M, N, X, HSI, and table are defined?  Could you also make it clearer what you are actually asking?

Answer (score 0):

A quick sketch, you can amend as necessary

```
import random

a=[] #start with an empty set
k=0
while k< 5:
    b=random.sample(range(1,100), 5) #get a random sample of length 5 within range of 1-100
    a.append(b) # add/'append' b to your currently empty set of 'a'
    print a #print current contents of 'a'
    k=k+1
```

I've not run this but it seems intuitive.

Good luck!